# Position:absolute inside position:relative doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I have table and tr i set tr position:relative and i add span element inside tr and give it position:absolute and left:0 but its positioning relative to html not my tr element

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.remove {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Logo</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Logo</td>
    <span class="remove">This should be on left side</span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Namer</td>
    <td>Logo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes this is by design, will try to find where exactly this is defined

Comment: why doesnt work

Comment: *The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.* --> tr is a table-row  (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)

Comment: What are trying to do? You are putting `span` directly inside `tr` element which is wrong. `<tr>` is always followed by `<td> or <th>`.

Comment: Also, you cannot use `<th>` directly inside `<table>`. It must come inside `<tr>`. Please follow table structure (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: @TemaniAfif - That's missing the point. The HTML parser has ejected the span and its contents from the table, so it doesn't have a `position:relative` ancestor.

Comment: @Alohci true, my comment was before he post the code. He also have display:block on the tr so it will work even if the HTML is correct. But without display:block it will fai on Chromel: https://jsfiddle.net/wcuakovg/2/ (on FF it works)

Comment: span cannot be a direct child of tr, put it inside a td, and it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/zLm3k124/ **first thing to check when css goes nuts** : Is my HTML valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the span tag in the table layout, which makes span outside the table. Use td tag for element.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.remove {
  all:initial;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Logo</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Logo</td>
    <td class="remove">This should be on left side</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Namer</td>
    <td>Logo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```